# Network centrality for pairs

Tags: graph-theory, network

As part of a research project, I am tasked with finding the most influential *pairs* in a weighted social network. That is, the intervention does not assign individuals, but pairs of friends (two nodes that are connected). I'm now looking for a mathematical way of solving this problem. My take was to use a well-established centrality measure (say, group indegree centrality) and then approach it as follows: 1. Find most central player, subset his/her friends, take the most group-central player among them. 2. Repeat with second pair, etc. I'm wondering if this is the best way to approach the problem. Particularly, I wonder if there are centrality measures that assess centrality for pairs (I haven't found any). I would be very grateful for feedback.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Probably too unspecified. Would not be surprised if voted for closure. ( needs more context or details, bla bla ) At least throw in "soft question" tag or to add some of the definitions of some of the words you are using could help.

Comment: Many node centralities can be straightforwardly translated to an *edge* or *link centrality* (there are your keywords). Whether one make sense for you depends on what makes an edge important to you. As it stands, I agree with @mathreadler that this question is too broad.

Comment: A general advice for analysing empirical networks: Do not focus so much on what measures exist or are popular, but what makes sense for your application and what answers the question you have. Also check whether the measure actually does what you want it to do. There is enough bullshit research out there where people throw mostly arbitrary measures at some data and then misinterpret the results because the measure was not suited for their question.